# How to alter type in pgsql?

Tags: database, postgresql, psql

I'm trying to add an attribute to an existing TYPE named student_info. When I execute the query in pgAdmin I get an error. How can I fix this?

This is my query:

```
ALTER TYPE student_info ADD ATTRIBUTE intake_date DATE;
```

This is the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ADD"
LINE 1: ALTER TYPE student_info ADD ATTRIBUTE intake_date DATE;
                            ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "ADD"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 25
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add your version of Postgres. More about *how to ask good questions* in the [info for the Postgres tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info).

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're using PostgreSQL 9.0 or older that doesn't offer the possibility to add or drop attributes. It was added in 9.1

See [ALTER TYPE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-altertype.html) in the documentation for your version.